# Проблема с подключением модулей js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firestore

Пытаюсь подключить firestore таким кодом

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");
```

Ругается на первую строчку: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Аутентификацию так вообще не подключал, и все работает. В доках написано, что нужно подключать и firebase, и firestore, и таким образом

Comment: Не уверен что проблема с `firebase`, скорее всего что-то не так с запуском скрипта, ибо ошибка гласит о том, что скрипт выполняется не в контенксте `Node.js`, так как невозможно найти `require`

Comment: проверьте, установлен ли node.js

Comment: Мне нравится коментарий выше :)

Comment: Node.js установлен, но я так понимаю, что этого недостаточно?)

Comment: Должно быть достаточно, покажите как вы запускаете скрипт.

Comment: А хрен его знает, за это отвечает WebStorm и конфигурация Javascript debug, она запускает весь проект, все страницы и скрипты

Comment: Там есть конфигурация node.js попробую настроить её

Comment: А как надо запускать скрипт?))0